# Why are countries sending financial and military aid to a Ukraine when it may be occupied? Isn't that just the same as giving aid to Russia?

Tags: russian-federation, military, ukraine

Despite the propaganda that says that Ukranian heroes are bravely resisting and pushing back the Russian invaders, the truth is that the war has been on-going for a mere 4 days, and the Russians are already closing in on Kiev and Kharkiv, the two biggest cities of Ukraine. If (when ...) they fall, it's over. The country will de facto be under Russian control. Everything east of the Dnipro river will also be controlled by the Russians soon, as the Russians slowly but surely encircle that region from both the north, south, and east.

With all this in mind, what is the rationale for providing financial and military aid to Ukraine, when they're fighting a losing battle and all that aid will end up in the hands of the Russians in a few weeks from now?

[image]
Source: https://mobile.twitter.com/JulianRoepcke/status/1497955971007750144?cxt=HHwWgIC90ZzB58kpAAAA

Answer (score 5):

Because Ukraine is still putting up a fight, [right now](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-60543087).

> Giving aid to Ukraine only seems to make sense if one believes that they can win

That's simply not so. Making it a pyrrhic victory for Russia may also be worth the minor expenditure that a few thousand AT/AA missiles cost.

Keep in mind that Germany has [just announced](https://www.dw.com/en/germany-commits-100-billion-to-defense-spending/a-60933724) they increase their own defense spending by 100 bn euros! In comparison with that, all the military aid sent to Ukraine is peanuts.

Also, you can [see](https://edition.cnn.com/videos/world/2022/02/27/russian-military-vehicles-destroyed-video-rs-vpx.cnn/video/playlists/russia-ukraine-military-conflict/) some of the results of mass AT on the ground. Entire Russian armored column smashed. (Frankly, I have the impression Russian commanders knew this could happen, so they appear to have committed their lighter armor as a "meat shield", perhaps hoping the Ukrainians would run out of missiles.)

Comment: This doesn't provide any information that I didn't already cover in my question. Let me repeat, in case you missed it: If it is known that Ukraine will soon be under Russian control, is that aid not likely to end up under Russian control too, when that occupation is at hand, which it likely will be in a few days/weeks? Giving aid to Ukraine only seems to make sense if one believes that they can win. Is that the belief shared by those providing aid, and if so, on what basis do they hold this belief?

Comment: It is not "Known" that it will soon be under Russian control and it doesn't appear that it will happen anytime soon.

Comment: Not to mention that, to have any chance of success in having a neutral/supportive Ukraine next door, Russia would need to take over with minimum bloodshed (presumably because Ukrainians had been misled by "evil-minded outside forces").  Every combat casualty on either side makes that goal ever less achievable and the likelihood of an ultimately free Ukraine, even after considerable time, more probable.

Comment: @Aiteru454  - I come a month and a half in the future, in which Russia still has not conquered Ukraine.